# Understanding Promises (using Bluebird and Node)

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm trying to use promises the "right way", and I'm confused about this situation. Following are two pieces of code. The first one works perfectly and the second one fails. I think they should work identically, but they don't. In both, the two records are created, but `isCrawlDue` finds the records only in the first one. I'm 99% positive that the bug is in how I've written this promise chain and not in the functions being called.

Here's the block that works as expected.

```
clearStatements()
.then(dbFinancials.addStatement("XYZ", "type", moment.utc([2014, 0, 31]), 3, "none")
     .then(function (added1) {
        assert.isTrue(added1, "First record not added.");
        dbFinancials.addStatement("XYZ", "type", moment.utc(), 4, "none")
        .then(function (added2) {
            assert.isTrue(added2, "Second record not added.");
            dataCollection.isCrawlDue("XYZ")
            .then(function (isDue) {
                assert.isTrue(isDue, "No need for a crawl detected.");
                done();
            });
        });
    }));
```

This code adds both statements but inside `isCrawlDue`, the two statements are not found. I know that `isCrawlDue` works because it works in the code above.

```
clearStatements()
.then(dbFinancials.addStatement("XYZ", "type", moment.utc([2014, 0, 31]), 3, "none"))
.then(dbFinancials.addStatement("XYZ", "type", moment.utc(), 4, "none"))
.then(dataCollection.isCrawlDue("XYZ")
      .then(function (isDue) {
          assert.isTrue(isDue, "No need for a crawl detected.");
          done();
      }));
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: It may in fact be because `isCrawlDue` is not yet defined, contrary to your suspicions. In your first case, the identifier `isCrawlDue` does not cause a reference lookup until its containing function is run (i.e., the `function (added2)` callback). In your second example, it is evaluated immediately.

Comment: When I throw in some console.log statements, I get "add statement,"
"add statement," and "isCrawlDue" in that order, indicating that they are happening in the order I expect. That said, I'm not sure that contradicts your statement of being "evaluated" immediately because it definitely doesn't work like I think it should. If I have to nest the promises, doesn't that sort of defeat the purpose of using them? Aren't they intended to overcome the deep nesting of callbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .then(dbFinancials.addStatement("XYZ", "type", moment.utc([2014, 0, 31]), 3, "none"))

Is not a correct usage of promises. `.then` accepts a function (that will be called when previous promise is resolved) but instead a `addStatement` function is called and result is provided as an argument to `.then`. 
So in first example there is a mistake that first `addStatement` is called immediately after `clearStatements()`, not waiting for it to resolve. The rest of the chain works ok.

In the second example, as absolutely correctly pointed by @apsillers, `clearStatements`, two `addStatement` and `isCrawlDue` are called one after another without waiting to resolve. Obviously `addStatement` hasn't pushed any info yet to be found by `isCrawlDue`.

To rewrite it in a proper way you should wrap `addStatements` in a function or use `bind` (because bind actually returns a function). I will use these different ways in snippet below to demonstrate what I mean

```
clearStatements()
.then(function(){
    return dbFinancials.addStatement("XYZ", "type", moment.utc([2014, 0, 31]), 3, "none")
})
.then(dbFinancials.addStatement.bind(dbFinancials, "XYZ", "type", moment.utc(), 4, "none"))
.then(function(){
    return dataCollection.isCrawlDue("XYZ");
})
.then(function (isDue) {
    assert.isTrue(isDue, "No need for a crawl detected.");
    done();
});
```

In both cases call to `addStatement` will be delayed till the previous operation is resolved. And `isCrawlDue` will be executed after the second `addStatement` is resolved

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you; your solution works and your narrative indicates that I still have some things to learn about the "best" or "proper" use of promises. Thanks for the lesson; there are definitely some subtle nuances to the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
clearStatements()
.then(dbFinancials.addStatement("XYZ", "type", moment.utc([2014, 0, 31]), 3, "none"))
.then(dbFinancials.addStatement("XYZ", "type", moment.utc(), 4, "none"))
.then(dataCollection.isCrawlDue("XYZ"))
.then(function (isDue) {
    assert.isTrue(isDue, "No need for a crawl detected.");
    done();
});
```

I added a second end parenthesis behind `dataCollection.isCrawlDue("XYZ")` and removed it from the end, so `.then` only wraps `dataCollection.isCrawlDue("XYZ")`.

`.then` returns a value and expects another promise, not a sequence of promises.